# How do I instantiate modules within case statements in Verilog HDL?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, state-machines

I am trying to make a sequence detector with 4 modes - Moore machine overlapping & non-overlapping and Mealy machine overlapping & non-overlapping.

But writing my code like this gives me an error:

```
module seq_det(
    input clk, rst_n, x,
    input [1:0] mode,
    output reg z
);
    
    case (mode)
        2'b00: moore_det_nonov SD1(clk, rst_n, x, z);
        2'b01: moore_det_ov SD2(clk, rst_n, x, z);
        2'b10: mealy_det_nonov SD3(clk, rst_n, x, z);
        2'b11: mealy_det_ov SD4(clk, rst_n, x, z);
    endcase
endmodule
```

Here I have made 4 modules separately which I am trying to instantiate. Here's one of them, others are similar:

```
module mealy_det_ov(input clk, rst_n, x, output reg z);
  parameter A = 4'h1;
  parameter B = 4'h2;
  parameter C = 4'h3;
  parameter D = 4'h4;
  
  reg [3:0] curr_state, next_state;

  always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
    curr_state <= rst_n ? next_state : A;
  end
  
  always @(curr_state or x) begin
    case(curr_state)
      A: next_state <= x ? B : A;         
      B: next_state <= x ? B : C;
      C: next_state <= x ? D : A;
      D: next_state <= x ? B : C;
      default: next_state = A;
    endcase
  end

    always @(curr_state) begin
        z <= (curr_state == D) ? 1:0;
    end
endmodule
```

I know what I am doing is wrong, so please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need four instances and a mux to switch the output between them.

If you instantiate this with `mode` set to a fixed value, the optimizer will remove those instances that are never connected to the output.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used conditional compilation and execution to instatiate the required module by defining the `mode` as a `macro` instead of an `input`.